# Gravitational Time Dilation Formula?

Tags: gravity, time, relativity

What is the equation for calculating the dilation of time at different levels of gravitational force?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation

Comment: -1. The question shows lack of research. A simple Google search can answer it.

Comment: The time dilation is dependant on the gravitational potential not the gravitational force.

Answer (score 2):

The "g-force" you would experience if you were to "hover" at Schwarzschild coordinate $r$ away from a spherical body of mass $M$ is given by:

$$g=\frac{GM}{r^2 \sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r}}}$$

(This only applies to bodies held at a fixed value of $r$. A body in freefall experiences no acceleration, for example. If $r$ is changing in some fashion then then above will differ. If the object you're considering is in orbit then it will also differ. It's called the "proper acceleration," if you want to know its fancy title.) Time dilation relative to a stationary observer far away from the mass is given by:

$$\frac{d\tau}{dt}=\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r}}$$

So in terms of g-force:

$$\frac{d\tau}{dt}=\frac{GM}{g r^2}$$

It is also interesting to notice that in Newtonian gravitation, where $\, g=GM/r^2$, the time dilation factor becomes 1. In other words, in Newtonian gravity there is no time dilation.

Comment: Jason should also be aware that these equations are specifically for an observer who is hovering at a constant position in Schwarzschild coordinates, they'd be different for an observer who was orbiting or falling towards the center.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Indeed. I'll edit my post accordingly.